# Expect Script Not Working for Automatic Server Shutdown

Tags: shell, websphere, expect, ibm-midrange

Let me preface this question by saying I am VERY new to using tools like Expect, so the solution to this may be rather simple and obvious.

We are trying to automate the shutdown of our WebSphere server on our AS400 for a specific process that we have to run monthly. This happens by calling a CL program that runs a QSH session from a statement file. Actually calling the expect program seems to work fine.

The issue we run into is that it seems whatever sort of internal variable (presumably exp0) the expect is using to compare the expected text to isn't actually being attributed a new value when new commands get ran. Here is code in the statement file that gets ran:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f                                    
set timeout 320                                               
exp_internal 1                                                

send "cd /qibm/proddata/websphere/appserver/v85/express/bin\r"
expect "$"                                                    

send "stopServer WAS85SVR\r"                                  
expect {                                                      
default {exit 2}                                              
"Username:" {send "username\r"; exp_continue}                 
"Password:" {send "password\r"; exp_continue}                 
"$"                                                           
}                                                             

expect "$"
```

The sends in the expect that say "username" and "password" would normally contain actual username and password text. Here is what gets dumped into the log file for the run:

```
send: sending "cd /qibm/proddata/websphere/appserver/v85/express/bin\r" to { exp0 cd /qibm/proddata/websphere/appserver/v85/express/bin
}

 expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "$"? yes        
 expect: set expect_out(0,string) ""                                
 expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp0"                            
 expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""                                  
 send: sending "stopServer WAS85SVR\r" to { exp0 stopServer WAS85SVR
}                                                                   

 expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "Username:"? no 
 "Password:"? no                                                    
 "$"? yes                                                           
 expect: set expect_out(0,string) ""                                
 expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp0"                            
 expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""                                  

 expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "$"? yes        
 expect: set expect_out(0,string) ""    
 expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp0"
 expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""
```

The "\r"s have been included just for log file readability and I don't believe they end up translating into the sends that are passed. Also, it may be worth noting that the "stopServer" command runs for about 10 seconds before the "Username:" prompt shows up. We've tried putting in a delay prior to expecting for "Username:", but that didn't seem to work either.

If it is worth seeing, here is what a manual/interactive session in QSH looks like up to the "Username:" prompt:

```
  $                                                                                                       
> cd /qibm/proddata/websphere/appserver/v85/express/bin                                                   
  $                                                                                                       
> stopServer WAS85SVR                                                                                     
  ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file /QIBM/UserData/WebSphere/AppServer/V85/Express/profiles/WAS85SVR/logs/WAS85SVR/stopServer.log
  ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the WAS85SVR profile                                                      
  ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: WAS85SVR                                                   
  Realm/Cell Name: <default>                                                                              
  Username:
```

Comment: According to the output from running stopServer at qsh prompt, your expect script should be looking for "Username:" and not "Username?"

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo I must have made when entering the code on here haha. Yes, normally it should be looking for "Username:" with the colon, but unfortunately the issue and error log remains the same.

Comment: Can I suggest an alternative option available to consider? You can keep the username and an encoded copy of the password inside a WebSphere property file. This allows the command-line scripts (stopServer, startServer, serverStatus) to run without prompting for authentication.

Comment: Hmmmm I never considered that. We can get single lines to execute just fine in the program so that might be a fix for our issue, though if anyone comes up with a reason why it seems like the program doesn't end up changing what it expects I'd be more than glad to hear it still. It's really bugging us!